# Get Facebook name with Parse on an Android app

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

When a user logs into Facebook, I'd like to get their name and profile picture. For the name, I was looking at [this link](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-id-of-a-user-logged-in-with-facebook) with this code:

```
private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (user != null) {
                    String facebookId = user.getId();
                }

        }
        if (response.getError() != null) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
});
request.executeAsync();
```

}

But I was unable to import the Request class and it looks like the class is [no longer available](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/Request/). Is there another class that could get the same job done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session class has been removed from the the SDK at the version 4.0 - at March 25, 2015. You can find information about this in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x)

Call newMeRequest using accressToken

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    String name = object.
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Parse? Instead, go directly to Facebook and use Graph API. Here's the link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph